# C# SQL Data Adapter System.Data.StrongTypingException

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I get my data from SQL to Dataset with Fill. It's just one table with two columns (CategoryId (int) and CategoryName (varchar)).

When I look at my dataset after fill method, CategoryId Columns seems to be correct. But in the CategoryName I have a **System.Data.StrongTypingExceptio**n.

**What could that mean?**

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you get the value of a row/column in a typed dataset, by default it raises this exception when the value is DBNull.
So

```
string x = Row.CategoryName;//Raises this exception when CategoryName is null.
```

You can correct this with the typed dataset designer.
**Set the property "Nullvalue" of the CategroyName column to "(Empty)"**